# ¿Cómo ejecutar varios Jobs en diferentes horarios usando Quartz?

Tags: c#, cron

Estoy intentado implementar Quartz en un API Rest en C# que tengo, tengo dos Jobs, el primero que se debe ejecutar cada 30 segundos y otro que necesito que se ejecute a media noche para hacer una consulta de unos usuarios de mi LDAP.

Hasta ahí todo bien, hice mis Jobs, cree los triggers y los llamo. El trigger de los 30 segundos lo cree usando `WithSimpleSchedule` y el de media noche intenté crearlo usando `WithCronSchedule`; cuando los ejecuto en mi equipo, ambos se activan correctamente, pero cuando los despliego en el servidor (publicando el API), solo queda activo el primer Job, no el segundo.

Lo resolví momentáneamente usando `WithSimpleSchedule` a 60 segundos y generando un `schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();` al llamar el segundo Job, creyendo que puede ser que el `StdSchedulerFactory` solo ejecuta un job a la vez, y verificando a cada minuto si ya eran las 00:00, algo que me parece más un parche que una verdadera solución.

Mi disparador de Jobs lo llamo en el `Global.asax.cs`

```cs
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

            Jobs jobs = new Jobs();
            jobs.Iniciar();
        }
    }
```

Y esta es mi clase Jobs:

```cs
 public class Jobs
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Función que inicia todos los trabajos que se tengan preparados
        /// </summary>
        internal async void Iniciar()
        {

            #region "Trabajos"
            // Se define el Job
            IJobDetail jobSesiones = JobBuilder.Create<VerificarSesionesAplicaciones>()
                .WithIdentity("verificarSesionesAplicaciones", "group1") //"Nombre", "grupo tareas"
                .Build();

            // Se define el Job
            IJobDetail jobUsuarioDA = JobBuilder.Create<VerificarUsuarioDirectorioActivo>()
                .WithIdentity("verificarUsuariosDirectorioActivo", "group1") //"Nombre", "grupo tareas"
                .Build();

            #endregion

            #region "Triggers para asignar a los jobs"
            // Los CRON para crear horarios personalizados pueden crearse acá http://www.cronmaker.com/

            // Trigger para correr un Job que inicia inmediatamente y se repite cada 30 segundos
            ITrigger trigger_30Seg = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("myTrigger30Seg", "group1") //Nombre, Grupo
              .StartNow()
              .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                  .WithIntervalInSeconds(30)
                  .RepeatForever()) //Se repite cada 30 segundos y nunca se detiene
              .Build();

            // Trigger para correr un Job que inicia inmediatamente y se repite cada 30 segundos
            ITrigger trigge2r_30Seg = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("myTrigger30Seg", "group1") //Nombre, Grupo
              .StartNow()
              .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                  .WithIntervalInSeconds(30)
                  .RepeatForever()) //Se repite cada 30 segundos y nunca se detiene
              .Build();

            // Trigger para correr un Job que inicia inmediatamente y se repite cada 60 segundos
            ITrigger trigger_1Minuto = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("myTriggerMinuto", "group1") //Nombre, Grupo
              .StartNow()
              .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                  .WithIntervalInSeconds(60)
                  .RepeatForever()) //Se repite cada 60 segundos y nunca se detiene
              .Build();

            // Trigger para correr un Job que se inicia a las 11:59pm y se repite cada 24horas
            ITrigger trigger_MediaNoche24hr = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("myTriggerMediaNoche24Horas", "group1") //Nombre, Grupo
              .StartNow()
              .WithCronSchedule("0 0 0 1/1 * ? *")
              .Build();

            // Trigger para correr un Job que se inicia a las 12 y se repite cada 12horas
            ITrigger trigger_MediaNoche12Horas = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("myTriggerMediaNoche12Horas", "group1") //Nombre, Grupo
              .StartNow()
              .WithCronSchedule("0 0 0/12 1/1 * ? *")
              .Build();

            #endregion

            #region "Lanzamiento de trabajos"
            ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
            await scheduler.Start();
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobSesiones, trigger_30Seg);

            schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
            await scheduler.Start();
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobUsuarioDA, trigger_MediaNoche24hr);

            #endregion

        }
    }
```

Quisiera ver si pueden ayudarme a determinar que es lo que estoy haciendo mal o en qué estoy fallando.

Comment: Duda, porque Quartz y no un windows service?

Comment: Para poderlo integrar directamente en mi API y no tener que hacer dos proyectos separados, tengo un servicio de windows ya, lo voy a pasar a Quartz para mantenerlo integrado todo en un solo proyecto, esa es la idea de usar quartz

Answer (score 0):

Utilice `Quartz` hace varios años, al final lo termine cambiando por varios `Windows Service`, ya que aunque tienes que crear otro proyecto al final a mi se me hizo mas facil mantener un `windows service` por el hecho de que puedes pararlo cuando tu quieras, si requieres un cambio no tienes que publicar todo tu proyecto web y es mas facil detectar si el problema es el proyecto web o el windows service.

En mi caso yo separe cada `Job` en una clase distinta y me funciono sin problemas, espero te sirva

JobScheduler

```
public class PasswordsJobScheduler
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail passwordsJob = JobBuilder.Create<PasswordsJob>().Build();

            var startTime = new DateTimeOffset(2017, 07, 01, 08, 00, 00, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

            ITrigger passwordsTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("Trigger", "PasswordsJob")
            .StartAt(startTime)
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInHours(24) //Cada 24 horas
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(passwordsJob, passwordsTrigger);

        }
    }
```

Ejecucion del Job

```
 public class PasswordsJob:IJob
    {

        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            //Mi Logica                

        }
    }
```

En mi Global.asax

```
PasswordsJobScheduler.Start();
```

Esto por cada job que requiero, es decir si tengo otro job, Hice otra clase de `JobScheduler` de ese Job, otra clase con la Ejecucion y en el `Global.asax` tambien llamar por separado ese `Start()`

Comment: No se si es la respuesta a tu problema, pero espero te pueda ayudar

Comment: En tu Job no usas `public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)`?, a mi me decia que debía usarlo así, con esa sintaxis

Comment: Qué haces con ese `DateTimeOffset`?, nunca lo he usado entonces no entiendo esa sintaxis jaja

Comment: No, en ningun momento llegue a declarar el execute como asyncrono

Comment: El DateTimeOffSet es como un DateTime, solamente lo use para declarar la fecha en que iniciara por 1a vez el Job. No recuerdo porque lo declare asi, tal ves me lo pedia asi

Comment: La hora la tengo en un Key en mi web.config (formato 24 horas), cómo hago para crear ese `DateTimeOffSet` que inicie a la hora que allí digan?, por ejemplo, si se coloca en el web.config 00:00 que el job se dispare esa noche a las 12 de la noche

Comment: var startTime = new DateTimeOffset(2019, 09, 10, 00, 00, 00, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0))